# R: How to find non-sequential elements in an array

Tags: arrays, r, sequential

I have an array with several numbers in it and I don't know beforehand what the numbers will be. I would like to separate out those numbers in the array which are not sequential to the previous number (in addition to the first number in the sequence).

For example:
Array: `2 3 4 5 10 11 12 15 18 19 20 23 24`

I would like to return `2 10 15 18 23`

The original array could be of variable length, including length zero

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
 v1 <- c(2:5,10:12,15, 18:20, 23:24)
 v1[c(TRUE,diff(v1)!=1)]
#[1]  2 10 15 18 23
```

#### Update

If you want to get the last sequential number, try

```
v1[c(diff(v1)!=1, TRUE)]
#[1]  5 12 15 20 24
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Quick question: if possible, how could I alter the above code to select the last sequential number i.e. instead of '2 10 15 18 23', select instead '5 12 15 20 24'? Thanks again!

Comment: We all reinvent the wheel, don't we :-( .  (See my self-promotion of `seqle`)  Note BTW that you could replace `!=1` with `!=0` to simulate `rle`, or `!=N` for any other stepped-sequence.

Answer (score 5):

Oddly enough :-),  I get to proffer one of my creations:  `cgwtools:seqle`  . `seqle` works just like `rle` but returns sequence runs rather than repetition runs.

```
 foo<- c(2,3,4,5,10,11,12,15,18,19,20,23,24)
 seqle(foo)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 4 3 1 3 2
  values : num [1:5] 2 10 15 18 23
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use function `lag` from package `dplyr`:

```
arr <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 15, 18, 19, 20, 23, 24)

index_not_sequential <- which(arr - dplyr::lag(arr, 1, default=-1 ) != 1)

arr[index_not_sequential]
```

gives

```
[1]  2 10 15 18 23
```

Comment: You either have dplyr version less than about zero or something is horribly wrong. Or you typed "Lag" instead of "lag". But I think you transcribed that error message rather than cut n paste it... So... weird...

Comment: Yeah it is weird, as I can definitely use other objects from the dplyr package. Yes, I transcribed the message. Thanks for the help though!